# QGIS - how to copy only some columns from attribute table

Tags: qgis

I often need to copy/paste a bunch of feature attributes from QGIS into something else (text editor, Excel, ...).

I can select everything then press Ctrl-C, but that adds a column with the geometry of the feature, which is very long and I have yet to find an instance where I actually want it.

My question is: how do I export selected attributes (i.e. columns), or at least, how do I suppress the geometry being included in the copy?

Right now I have to paste into Excel, delete the geometry which is cumbersome because the rows are tall because the text wraps in them, delete other columns I don't want, select/copy everything again, then paste in final destination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the QGIS option there is a setting that let you choose how feature are copied. If you choose the "Plain Text, No Geometry" option it should solve the problem with geometry being added to your excel sheet.

[image]

A more direct way to get the file you want is to use the "Save Vector Layer As..." fonction, it will let you choose the export format (including Excel and CSV) and witch field to export (you can even change field name). There is a tick-box to let you export all feature or only selected feature…

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Settings -> Options, choose data Sources, then choose 'Plain Text, no geometry' from the drop down
[image: options]